# Mysql vs Parse.com

Tags: android, mysql, ios, parse-platform

My app is growing very fast, and we have used Parse.com as the main database.

We want to create a web version of this to work together with the app for iOS and Android.

The only limitation that we know from Parse.com is that the queries max limit is 1000, so after it you need to create a function to do more queries.

So talking about a very large database, performance on server-side, Users doing queries using 3g network and scalability, is a good way move it to mysql?

- Not considering time and cost.
- Only talking about performance, scalability and queries to work with Android, iOS and web.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell me the name of this app so I can NOT buy it, so it doesn't drain me of my data allowance over 3G getting more than 1000 records of data at a time that I probably don't need to see all at once. Seriously, think about your architecture if you need to get more than 1000 records at a time over a mobile data connection.

Comment: I'm not telling that my app do a query with 1000 records, but the cloud code could do it.

Comment: Perhaps explain a little more about what you're trying to do if you want people to provide you with better suggestions. Currently it reads as "I have this problem I'm not explaining that exhibits this symptom I'm being vague about, I've decided on this solution, help me justify it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of scalability I guess you really need to worry about that if you are managing your own servers.  Worse case, you go with a professional hosting service but use VPS.

Parse uses mongoDB which is entirely different than MySQL.  The 1000 limit should really be an issue regardless of what database you use because you should be structuring your app that you don't grab anywhere near 1000 items at once.  That is where lazy loading comes into play.

Parse is a `REST` API.  This means you're using HTTP requests to get information.  You will need to write an API or find an open source option to put on your server.  You need to make sure that your code runs efficiently so you can get results fast and put as little strain as possible on your servers.

Another thing is to try and prevent having 1000 queries. If there's a way where you can download data that can be reused in the app instead of re-downloading it each time then do it.  Less strain on servers, quick response, and little data going back and forth.

That's really all I have to offer.

Comment: Yes, I actually uses a Cloud Server to manage HTTP requests, in the whole content I should keep with Parse.com, the only cons that I found is the risk of Parse quality service, If I need to move out from them later, I will have trouble. But until now its working very well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would help you, but I'm moving stuff out as well, but you are comparing two different databases to each other. I'm moving my data to Cassandra or MongoDB, that's because the data is key value. As for mysql, I hope you keep in mind, a lot of companies use it for large scale problems and they run it fine. I hope this helps.